# Checking if varchar column value containing IP address is in subnet

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

In SQL (tried in pgAdmin) I am able to do

```
SELECT * FROM ...
WHERE inet(s.ip_address) << `10.0.0.2/24`
```

I tried to convert it to django ORM code which contained following:

```
... .filter(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)
```

But I am getting

```
Unsupported lookup 'net_contained' for CharField
```

I understand that this is because `s.ip_address` is of type varchar. In SQL, I am explicitly converting it to IP using `inet()`. How do I do the same in django ORM? Does [this](https://github.com/jimfunk/django-postgresql-netfields/issues/24) thread say its is unsupported?

Comment: Will you only use IPv4? In that case one can easily make a custom field for this.

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that this is because `s.ip_address` is of type varchar. In SQL, I am explicitly converting it to IP using `inet()`.

**No**, the query is *never* passed to the database. Django simply does not know what `net_contained` means.

Likely you tried to find help, and somehow found a manual for this [**`django-netfields`** <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-netfields/) package. This package defines a field named `InetAddressField`. This field uses `INET` in the database, but more importantly, also defines lookups like `__netcontained` than can then be translated to a query.

We thus can install this package with:

```
pip install django-netfields
```

Then we use this field on our model instead:

```
from netfields import InetAddressField, NetManager


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ip_address = InetAddressField()

    objects = NetManager()
```

and finally, we can filter with:

```
MyModel.objects.filter(ip_address__net_contained='10.0.0.2/24')
```

Comment: Very sorry for super late response. I wanted to get all records for which `ip_address` is not contained in the given subnet. I tried `MyModel.objects.exclude(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)`. This gives me error `Unsupported lookup 'net_contained' for InetAddressField`. As per [this](https://github.com/jimfunk/django-postgresql-netfields/issues/26) post, we have to add `netfields` to `INSTALLED_APPS`. But now it returns value as `172.18.1.1/32` and not `172.18.1.1`. Record contains `172.18.1.1`, why it is returning `172.18.1.1/32`?

Comment: @MsA: because it is an `ip_interface` object. You can access its IP, with `mymodel.ip_address.ip`. The rest is the mask which is here 32, so all bits are significant.

Comment: Then, how one is supposed to obtain just the IP? I tried `.values( .. , 'ip_address_ip',  ... )`, it gives `Cannot resolve keyword 'ip_address_ip' into field.`. Also tried double underscore: `.values( .. , 'ip_address__ip',  ... )`. It gives `Cannot resolve keyword 'ip' into field.`.

Comment: @MsA: please *don't* use `.values()`, it is a *horrible* antipattern: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: So what can be done to get rid of `values`?

Comment: @MsA: extactly *what* do you want to do? If you want to serialize data, you use a serializer: this will also work bi-directional https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/

Comment: Here is [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/GpKPkNus) for my SQL and corresponding django ORM query. I am basically trying to find two logins happening from same IP.

Comment: @MsA: but didn't you do that through the `.filter(..)`. The *processing* of the data to convert it to some format is *not* something you should do by the ORM. The ORM should be used to retrieve and manipulate data in the database, not format it into a JSON blob, or something similar, so afterwards, you turn the `access_logs` into JSON blobs, for example with a serializer.

Comment: ohkay I guess I am getting it but not crystal clear. Some article link or perhaps chatgpt prompt?

Comment: Well, again sorry for coming back and bothering. I have two REST endpoints, one with `.exclude(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)` and other with `.filter(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)`. Both are now giving error `ValueError: 0.0.0.2/24 has host bits set` where `0.0.0.2/24` is my input from UI. [Here](https://pastebin.com/2y9aGHGv) is full stack trace. I guess this was working earlier. But dont know whats changed now!!!

Comment: (continuing from last comment) ohh its the value `10.0.0.2/24` gives error `ValueError: 10.0.0.2/24 has host bits set`, whereas `172.18.0.0/24` does not! Now I understand that all bits for host need to be zero. In, `10.0.0.2/24`, its 2. If I try `10.0.0.0/24`,  it works. Now I am thinking how can I make `10.0.0.2/24` to work !