# `ValueError: %s has host bits set` while using InetAddressField in django model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `InetAddressField` from `django.netfields` to store IP address in DB. I followed steps from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76399799/6357916).

I have following model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    // some fields ...
    ip_address = InetAddressField()

    objects = NetManager()
```

I have two REST end points, one with

```
MyModel.objects.exclude(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)
```

and another with

```
MyModel.objects.filter(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)
```

where `subnet_mask` is input from UI.

Now the thing is all bits for host need to be zero in subnet mask. In, `10.0.0.2/24`, its 2. So it gives error as follows:

```
ERROR [2023-06-15 20:49:41,326] [django.request] [log] [Process:2090] [Thread:139874097665792] Internal Server Error: /my_module/my_rest_endpoint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/myapp/my_module/views.py", line 484, in my_rest_endpoint
    .exclude(ip_address__net_contained=subnet_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 899, in exclude
    return self._filter_or_exclude(True, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 908, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(~Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1290, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1318, in _add_q
    split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1251, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1116, in build_lookup
    lookup = lookup_class(lhs, rhs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/netfields/lookups.py", line 68, in get_prep_lookup
    return str(ipaddress.ip_network(self.rhs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 74, in ip_network
    return IPv4Network(address, strict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/ipaddress.py", line 1519, in __init__
    raise ValueError('%s has host bits set' % self)
ValueError: 10.0.0.2/24 has host bits set
```

If I try `10.0.0.0/24`, it works as host ID (last octet) is `0`. How can I make `10.0.0.2/24` work?